# Filezilla root access to aws ubuntu instance

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, filezilla

I just set up an aws ubuntu instance on Amanzon. I am trying to upload/create new files with filezilla on my apache server folder (/var/www/) but i only have access to "/home/ubuntu/". 
Is there a way to access other folders through filezilla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but as far as i know, you will have to log into SSH to created / edit folders and change the owner or group permissions before you can do anything with FileZilla.

Comment: thank you! i used chmod to give permission to my folder. i guess i should set them back to original afterwards right?